# PHP Form Validtion not working - Need error result next to element

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

PHP Novice here again.

I have searched and tried various things, but still cannot get it to work... basically I have a lengthy form that required the user to complete almost all fields to be able to submit correctly, but I would like the form to list the errors next to the element.

I have used this [code](http://www.smarttutorials.net/send-an-e-mail-with-attachment-using-jquery-ajax-and-php-without-refrshing-a-page/) , so I would like something similar to how it displays errors, then if all good it will divert to a "custom thank you page".

Here is my code:

```
(function() {

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            //return $('#mailForm').validate().form();
            $("#mailForm").validate({
                 rules: {
                    name: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 2
                    },
                    name2: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 2
                    },
                    ic-passport: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 6
                    },
                    phone: { 
                      required : true,
                      number:true,  
                      minlength : 10,
                      maxlength : 13
                    },
                    city: {
                       required: true,
                       minlength : 4
                    },
                    email:{ 
                       required: true,
                       email: true
                    },
                    dob: {
                       required: true,
                       date: true
                       minlength : 4
                    },
                    sex: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    tpt: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    licence: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    travel: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    language: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    ethnicity: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    religion: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    age: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    hair-colour: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    hair-length: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    eye-colour: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    height: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    weight: {
                       required: true,
                    },
                    image1: "required",
                    bio: "required",
                    experience: "required",
                    femail:{ 
                       required: true,
                       email: true
                    }
                 },
                 messages: {
                        name: {
                           required:"Please enter your name",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid name"
                        },
                        name2: {
                           required:"Please enter your name",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid name"
                        },
                        ic-passport: {
                           required:"Please enter your IC/Passport Number",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid IC/Passport Number"
                        },
                        phone: { 
                           required: "Please enter your phone number",
                           minlength: "Please enter your valid phone number",
                           maxlength: "Please enter your valid phone number"
                        },
                        city: { 
                           required: "Please enter your City/Town & State",
                           minlength: "Please enter your valid City/Town & State",
                        },
                        email:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your email",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        },
                        dob:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Date of Birth",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
                        },
                        sex:{ 
                           required: "Please select your Gender",
                        },
                        tpt:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you own Transport",
                        },
                        licence:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you own a Licence",
                        },
                        travel:{ 
                           required: "Please select if you are willing to Travel",
                        },
                        language:{ 
                           required: "Please select what Language you speak",
                        },
                        ethnicity:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Ethnicity",
                        },
                        religion:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Religion",
                        },
                        age:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Age",
                        },
                        hair-colour:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Hair Colour",
                        },
                        hair-length:{ 
                           required: "Please select your Hair Length",
                        },
                        eye-colour:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Eye Colour",
                        },
                        height:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Height",
                        },
                        weight:{ 
                           required: "Please enter your Weight",
                        },
                        image1: "Please Choose at least 1 Photo",
                        bio: "Please enter your Bio",
                        experience: "Please enter your Experience",
                        femail: { 
                           required: "Please enter your email",
                           minlength: "Please enter a valid email address",
                        }
                 },
                 debug: true,
                 errorElement: "em",
                 errorContainer: $("#warning, #summary"),
                 errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo( element.parent("td").next("td") );
                 },
                 success: function(label) {
                    label.text("ok!").addClass("success");
                 }  
             });
             var flag= $('#mailForm').valid();
             if(!flag){
                 return false;
             }
        },
        success: function(msg) {
           alert(msg);
           //$("#mailForm").addClass("hide");
           //$("#message1").show();
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            $("#mailForm").addClass("hide");
            $("#message1").show();
            $('#status').html(xhr.responseText);    
        }
    }); 
    $('#close').click(function(){ 
      $('#message1').hide();
      $("#mailForm").removeClass("hide");
      $('input[type=text],input[type=email],textarea,input[type=tel],input[type=date],input[type=url],input[type=file]').val('');
      location.reload();
     });
    })();
```

Comment: You should see `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -` because you have keys like `hair-colour` should be like `"hair-colour":{}`

Comment: No, all keys has dash - should be "key-name" like `eye-colour` , `ic-passport`, `hair-colour` should be between double quotes like `"eye-colour"` , `"ic-passport"`, `"hair-colour"`

Comment: Test and get back

Comment: If I open the form and just go straight to the submit, it doesn't validate... just puts one message in plain text on a blank page saying... invalid address.

Comment: Any further help anybody?